# Conditional PDF - Scaled Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> If $f_{X|A}(x|a)$ is the probability distribution function (pdf) of random variable $X$ given $A$, then what is the pdf of $X$ given $c A$ where $c$ is a positive constant independent of $A$ and $X$?

My answer: Let $A'=c A$. We have to find $f_{X|A'}(x|a)$. Then:

\begin{align}
f_{X|A'}(x|a)=\frac{f_{X,A'}(x,a)}{f_{A'}(a)}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{da}P(X<x,cA'<a)}{\frac{d}{da}f_(A'<a)}&=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{da}P(X<x,A<a/c)}{\frac{d}{da}f_(A<a/c)}\\
&=\frac{(1/c)f_{X,A}(x,a/c)}{(1/c)f_A(a/c)}\\
&={f_{X|A}(x|a/c)}
\end{align}

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. Alternatively you could have used a Jacobian transformation method to arrive at the joint distribution of $(X, A')$. Specifically, $Y = X$ and $A' = cA$ will lead to,

$$ f_{Y,A'}(y,a') = f_{X,A}\left(y,\frac{a}{c}\right)\frac{1}{c} $$

which is the same as the result you obtained in the numerator of your conditional pdf.